# MIPS Architecture : NOP (No-Operation) Vs Data Forwarding in Hazard Prevention

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I learnt in computer architecture course that, data hazard can be prevented by using several arbitrary, independent nop instructions in between two mutually dependent instructions. This can be done at assembly level in compiler design.

The alternative way to avoid data hazard is to use data forwarding.

I am bit confused, How these two alternatives differ as far as performance, speed and hardware is concerned. Because as per my knowledge data forwarding is to be implemented at hardware level, whereas nop can be implemented at assembly level.

Anybody please explain me which approach is better if we consider factors such as performance, speed, hardware etc?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, having the compiler insert nops into the code stream to fill pipeline slots allows hardware to be simplified which can reduce the duration of a pipeline stage or the depth of the pipeline, reduce design effort (time to market, project risk, design cost), or allow a full processor core to fit on a single chip (which helps performance). *However*, this benefit is tiny compared to the loss of performance from not using forwarding.  Higher latency for dependent instructions is very bad for typical programs.

The MIPS R2000, which had both delayed branches *and* delayed loads, provided result forwarding.  ([MIPS is an acronym for "Microprocessor without Interlocked Pipeline Stages"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878994/what-is-an-interlocked-pipeline-as-in-the-mips-acronym)).  Delayed loads were soon removed from MIPS (which was possible because such did not affect binary compatibility of correct code). The use of delayed instructions was partially from a belief that most delay slots could be filled by the compiler with useful instructions and partially from believing that the increase in code size was not important relative to the simplification of hardware.

Reducing the latency of a load operation was not practical, so the pipeline would need to be stalled for a cycle anyway. The cost of a nop is in cache and memory capacity effects (i.e., the effect of lower code density), and in some cases a single load delay slot could be filled.

Exposing the pipeline organization also has implications for binary compatibility. Later binary compatible implementations must accommodate the ISA designed for the original pipeline organization. A single delayed branch slot works reasonably well for a [simple 5-stage scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) implementation (it can be filled with a useful instruction most of the time and allows zero-effective-delay branches [i.e., no stall to resolve the branch or prediction and flushing the pipeline on misprediction]), but when the pipeline is deepened (or made wider) prediction or stalling becomes necessary anyway.

**If** sufficient parallelism exists in the targeted workloads, hardware simplicity is sufficiently important, and binary compatibility is not a problem, then exposing a pipeline with minimal support for dynamically detecting and handling stall conditions may be sensible. (There are also ways of encoding nops that avoid most of the code size expansion issues.) Having reliably sufficient parallelism (whether instruction-level or thread-level) allows the avoiding of nops; by compiler scheduling with instruction-level parallelism or by hardware thread interleaving with thread-level parallelism.

Hardware simplicity tends to reduce energy per unit of work (as well as chip area), and many modern designs are limited by power use. It also makes sense to perform optimizations at compile time (when they are less latency critical and can be done once rather than each time the code is executed) *if* the storage and communication cost of additional information is not too expensive (assuming information necessary to perform the optimization is available at compile time [dynamic branch prediction is a classic example of where dynamic information is helpful]).

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically since hardware is optimised with feed forwarding, there has to be no use of explicitly declared software NOPs. But that's not the case.
Though, feed forwarding proves helpful in reducing data hazards, but some hazards cannot be dealt with feed forwarding. It just isn't possible.
Eg.

1. beq R1,R5,label
2. instruction 2nd

Here the instruction 2nd will not be fetched until instruction 1 has completed its execution stage and decided whether or not to branch. Until then the 2nd instruction has to be stalled. (stalled for 2 memory cycles). This is done by software by sending out NOPs. 
With improvements in technology and hardware optimizations, the beq instruction can complete its execution stage in its register fetch/decode stage by inserting a comparator in the fetch stage itself. Even so, the 2nd instruction will be stalled for(1 memory cycle now). Again NOP is needed.

Comment: Not all stalls are implemented using NOP's actually.  Some control units have built-in mechanism for asserting/de-asserting certain bits along the data path, usually setting them to 0, which has the same net effect as a NOP, but is implemented differently.